# Run Appium in headless mode via Java

Tags: java, appium

Is there a way to run Appium tests in headless mode (like PhantomJS for selenium)?

I tried these caps but it doesn't work:

```
caps.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Android_9-5i");
caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "9");
caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
caps.setCapability("isHeadless", true);

caps.setCapability("appPackage", "XXX");
caps.setCapability("appActivity", "XXX");
caps.setCapability("avd", "Android_9-5i");
```

I got this line:

```
caps.setCapability("isHeadless", true);
```

from the appium documentation, but it still open the emulator though.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the correct way and generally it works, make sure you are running the latest Appium server version: **[v1.9.1](https://github.com/appium/appium/releases/tag/v1.9.1)**

Also there is a known **workaround**: 

`caps.setCapability("avdArgs", "-no-window");`

Which is doing [exactly the same](https://github.com/appium/appium-android-driver/blob/master/lib/android-helpers.js#L139)

If it won't work, it maybe be related to emulator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the emulator is opened with the args added, I'll try to check if I have a problem with my emulator

Comment: I am having the same problem of emulator still opening inspite of `isHeadless = true` Any ideas?